How to see Metro bundler logs separately for Android and iOS
I am developing a react-native mobile application and testing on both Android and iOS simulators at the same time. The thing is when we run npx react-native start it starts the metro bundler and then asks for android or iOS commands. When we select one of them it starts the app and prints logs for it but when at the same time we start the other it gives logs in the same terminal window. This way I am not able to figure out from which platform the logs are coming.
I want to view both platform logs differently. Is there a way or other methods to print logs separately?

TLDR; You can change the port number for iOS and keep the same port for android. Then run two terminals with each and you should be able to see logs separately.
Run for android

Build for android and let it run

Running different for the iOS

Go to your ios/[projectName].xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file and
search for 8081.

Replace it with 8082

then go to different terminal than the one running android and do yarn start --port 8082



I can't find any port specification or number in ios/[projectName].xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file.

which react native version are you in

It's react-native 0.74.3.

A port number should be there, can you attach your pbxproj file

The quickest way, in my opinion, would be to use the Platform method from react-native.

Platform

UseCase
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

...

 if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
    console.log("Hello from iOS");
 } else {
    console.log("Hello from other");
 }

...

 {
   Platform.OS === "ios" ? <Some iOS component /> : <Some Android component/>
 }

...

